# return the largest array between arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner in Javascript and I should write a code to solve this problem: Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array. For simplicity, the provided array will contain exactly 4 sub-arrays. and write this code can u tell me what is the problem him thnx:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var pos = 0;
    var max = 0;
    var add = 0;
    var sum = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if (j === 4) {
                sum[i] = add;
            } else {
                add = add + arr[i];
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (sum[i] > max) {
                max = sum[i]
                pos = i;
            }
        }
        return arr[pos];
    }
largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: Can you format your code to be a bit more readable? The easiest way is to put three back ticks (\`) on a single line, then your code on the following lines, and then follow that with three more back ticks (\`) on a new line by themselves.

Comment: Or use a stack snippet and press the tidy button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no restrictions, you could take

- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting a new array with
- [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) for getting a maximum number and take
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for converting an array to parameters.

```js
const largestOfFour = array => array.map(a => Math.max(...a));

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

For a more classic style, you could separate the functions, one for processing the outer array and one for getting a maximum value.

```js
function max(array) {
    var max = array[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (max < array[i]) max = array[i];
    }
    return max;
}

function largestOfFour(array) {
    var result = [];
    for (let a of array) result.push(max(a));
    return result;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```